# Creating reports based on data in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, report

I am trying to create several reports displaying date-related information based on mongoDB. For example, I need to show the number of registrations of users per day in the past 30 days. Each user document has a registered date field. I need to show the number of matching records (sum) per day on my report.

Is map-reduce an option? or is it too heavy?

Any suggestions on how to approach?

I am using spring to access mongo. But my questions is more about how to query mongoDB.

Comment: MongoDB has an ability to [group()][1] records in a similar way SQL GROUP BY would do. But all over that documentation they mention that you should use [map/reduce][2] instead.

Comment: [1]: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group
[2]: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Comment: Thanks but is there  way to perform query on date object only 'yyyy-MM-dd' and Ignore the 'HH:mm:ss'

Answer (score 1):

Map/reduce is extremely flexible and can do things that would be hard using other techniques, but it won't be as fast or as resource-efficient as less flexible methods if the less flexible methods do what you need.  I think that's the source of the idea that it is "heavy".  You could write a map/reduce pair of functions to do what db.collection.find({a:1}).count() does but the count() solution will be faster.

From your description, map/reduce sounds like a reasonable approach.  It gives you the flexibility to adjust your grouping based on other fields in the documents if you need to, which might be helpful if your documents aren't quite uniform.  A map/reduce job will add load to the server, so if you are barely keeping up with a high rate of inserts or updates it might not be a great addition, but that applies to any added workload.  If you have the ability to do it, testing and benchmarking the performance impact is the best plan.